# Quel temps doit-on utiliser après « que » ?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, subordonnées

On dit

> tu es la fille la plus jolie que je **connaisse**

mais aussi

> c'est par accident que je te **connais**

Quelle est la règle pour savoir quel temps utiliser ?

Comment: Quelle est la question ? par rapport au temps utilisé ? connais / connaisse ?

Comment: Au fait ce n'est pas trop une réponse à une question. C'est juste une déclaration que je voudrais former dans un texte. Je suis dans l'embarras. Je ne sais si je dois dire ...par un accident que je te connais ou connaisse. Puisque j'ai déjà entendu ..la fille la plus jolie que je  connaisse.

Comment: J'ai édité la question. Est-ce qu'elle reflète la même idée que voulue ?

Comment: this could help http://grammaire.cordial-enligne.fr/manuels/QUE_INDSUB.htm

Answer (score 3):

La question qui se pose ici est le mode à utiliser, avec un choix entre l'indicatif présent (je connais) et le subjonctif présent (je connaisse)

La règle générale pour l'emploi du subjonctif est que le verbe est mis en doute (action incertaine). Lorsque la chose est sûre, on emploiera de préférence l'indicatif. Cette règle n'est toutefois pas une règle absolue et certaines constructions imposent le mode à utiliser, comme après certains verbes (aimer que, demander que, ordonner que, permettre que, faire attention que...) ou certaines locutions conjonctives (bien que, pour que, avant que, jusqu'à ce que, à moins que, non que...)

Grammaticalement, les deux phrases sont donc correctes car il faut les regarder dans leur ensemble.

Pour la première phrase, le superlatif "le plus ... que" est généralement suivi du subjonctif. Rarement, on peut utiliser l'indicatif, par exemple je dirais "tu es la plus belle fille que je connais dans cette école"(entendu que je connais toutes les filles). Dans la plupart des cas, on est plus honnête en admettant que l'on ne connait pas toutes les filles du monde. Je pencherais donc plutôt pour le subjonctif (rem : le doute n'est pas sur "la plus belle" mais sur "connaître").

Dans le second exemple, il n'y a aucun doute sur le fait de connaître la personne: il faut utiliser l'indicatif.

```
C'est par accident que je te connais.
```

Comment: l'affirmation comme quoi "le plus ... que " est généralement suivi du subjonctif est excessive. Ce qui différencie est bien la certitude ou le doute. Toutes les constructions avec des affirmations au passé prendront l'indicatif. C'est d'ailleurs aussi l'explication de l'autre phrase. Le type de verbe est aussi un facteur: que je connaisse (doute). que je vois (certitude), dont je me souvienne, que je puisse (doutes)

Answer (score 2):

Ce n'est pas *que* qui indique le mode(1) qui doit suivre, mais ce qui précède *que*.

C'est le superlatif *la fille la plus jolie* qui demande le [subjonctif](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/superlative-subjunctive/), et le manque d'une construction particulière dans l'autre phrase qui permet l'indicatif.

(1) *Je connais* = présent de l'indicatif, *je connaisse* = présent du subjonctif. Ce sont des [modes](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verb-mood/) plutôt que des temps.